# What Spring Form backing object should be in the form where I want to pass a value from dropdown?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a form:

```
<f:form>
    <f:select path="refmap" onchange="myMethod();" name="tableName" id="tableName" >
        <f:options items="${valmap}"/>
    </f:select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" formAction="return constructUrl()"/></f:form>
```

Mentioned functions, but guess they aren't the big issue here:

```
        function myMethod(){
            var e = document.getElementById("tableName");
            var tableName = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        }
        function constructUrl(){
            var e = document.getElementById("tableName");
            var tableName = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            return "/spravochnik/list/"+tableName;
```

part of my controller leading to this page:

```
        Map refmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        refmap.put("tableMap", valmap);
        mod.addAttribute("refmap", refmap);
        mod.addAttribute("command", refmap);
```

valMap just has names of tables (that's what I'm using in dropdown);
The thing is, the jsp is swearing at me for refmap not having valid gettter/setter. I just want to pass along the dropdown value and nothing else. What backing object should I choose?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do similar to this with your code and try ? It works for me.

```
<select name="country">
    <c:forEach items="${countries}" var="country">
        <option value="${country.key}">${country.value}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: I have a requirement to use f:select only, not the usual select... resolved it by creating a new java class HomeForm with only one field nameOfTable and making a map with all names of tables. The ModelAttribute here is just a new HomeForm and then it understands all! Thanks anyway though!